# Office.js escape special characters in search

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm attempting to do a relatively straight-forward search (not through the UI, but programmatically) with wildcards but I'm having issues with special characters.

Inside the document, I have some data like this: `{name:2003}`, `{otherName:2005}` and maybe something like `{name:2003b}` (those are citekeys). I want to search them like this:

```
context.document.body.search('{*}', {matchWildCards: true});
```

But the issue is that `{` and `}` are special characters as described here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/searchoptions - there's even a part at the bottom about escaping the special characters programmatically, but I still don't get it. It says "...to escape it programmatically, put it between '' characters...". I've tried a couple of variations, all without success, I get an error each time when I try the search.

What is the correct way to escape these characters for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typo in article. To escape a character, you put it between square brackets; the '[' and ']' characters. So to escape "{", you use [{].